# Function injection in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, function-pointers

I have a random number generator (RNG) function.

```
-(double) generateRandomNumber
{
   ... do some stuff
   return randomNumber;
}
```

I have a function that calls this random number generator function to do a task - something along the lines of

```
-(double) GenerateSellPrice {
   double randomNumber;

   randomNumber = [self generateRandomNumber];

   return value*randomNumber;
}
```

I want to modify this so that the random number generator function is actually passed into the GenerateSellPrice function, so that I can swap in and out different RNGs for different purposes (i.e. unit testing, different ranges, etc).

How do I declare the RNG function so that it is in a form that I can pass it around (I'm assuming as a function pointer)? How do I declare the GenerateSellPrice to accept the function as a parameter? And how do I then invoke the function?

Comment: Have placed a solution of my own which I will select as its a more complete answer, however I have given upvotes to the answers that helped me get to there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out using blocks.  For those who want to know how I did it, I declared my RNG in my calling class (classA) as a class variable

```
double(^generateRandomNumber)(void) = ^{   
   ...do stuff;   
   return randomNumber; 
};
```

Then declared my function in my called class (classB)

```
-(double) generateSellPriceWithGenerator:(double(^)(void))generator {
   double randomNumber;

   randomNumber = generator();

   return value*randomNumber;
}
```

And then simply called the function from classA like so

```
double (^func)(void) = generateRandomNumber;
double value = [classB generateSellPriceWithGenerator:func];
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic Objective-C pattern would be to take a selector (`SEL`) and object (`id`) argument argument:

```
  -(double) GenerateSellPriceWithRNG:(id)rngObject selector:(SEL)rngSelector
       double randomNumber;

       randomNumber = [rngObject performSelector:rngSelector];

       return value*randomNumber;
    }
```

and call it with

```
[self GenerateSellPrinceWithRNG:self selector:@selector(generateRandomNumber)];
```

Modern practice would probably take a block (`double (^)()`) parameter. The syntax for a block is slightly uglier, but the power it brings is useful in this scenario. You get better type-checking from the compiler and you can easily generate a block inline where convenient rather than having to write an entire class & method.

In this case you could declare

```
-(double) GenerateSellPriceWithRNG:(double (^)())rngBlock {
   double randomNumber;

   randomNumber = rngBlock();

   return value*randomNumber;
}
```

and call it with

```
[self GenerateSellPriceWithRNG:^{ return [self generateRandomNumber]; }];
```

or with any other block that returns a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare your PRNGs as Objective-C blocks and pass them around like any other object. http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html has some info on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to use the "selector" object. You can declare a selector by doing the following

```
@selector(generateRandomNumber)
```

Once you have a selector object, you use

```
SEL randomNumberFunction; // Most likely passed in as a parameter
NSObject *generatorObject;
[generatorObject performSelector:randomNumberFunction];
```